# iOS: stretching Table View Cell in landscape mode

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I have a Table View Cell inside a Table View.
It is nicely positioned in Portrait mode.
How can I make it stretch the content in Table View Cell to fit the whole width?
If not, can iOS has 2 type of layouts like in Android?
For example we can create a layout to cater portrait and the other cater for landscape orientation?

Comment: If you haven't already, check out Auto Layout.

Comment: hmm.. let me try it out first.. thx for the tips ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can have both. Either you use autolayout to define how things should scale, or cou can switch to different view controllers respectively storynoards when the device orientation changes.
Your creativity is the limit here.